# Having trouble writing multi-line text into table cell

Tags: java, wicket

I am using Java Wicket to create a table. I want to write a cell made of multiple lines; each line within the cell represents a data item.

```
List<EntityClassModel> classesList = classService.getClassesByNotificationId(nitem.getModelObject().getId());
nitem.add(new Label("classnamelab", getClassNames(classesList)));
```

However, when I concatenate the lines, inside `getClassNames`, using `classNames.append("<br>");` the page displays `Latin 101<br>Latin 103`. From Chrome I Save As the page and opened it in Notepad++. It showed `<td class="laclasses">Latin 101&lt;br&gt;Latin 103</td>`.

I also tried the code `classNames.append("&lt;br&gt;");`. It was displayed in the cell as `Latin 101&lt;br&gt;Latin 103`, which is worse.

Using the saved files, I copied a row and changed the text to `<td class="laclasses">Angle 101<br>Bracket 103</td>`. That showed the data `Angle 101` and `Bracket 103` on two lines within the cell, which is what I want. Developer Tools showed the coding on five lines.

```
<td class="laclasses">
   "Angle 101"
   <br>
   "Bracket 103"
</td>
```

The style sheet includes the block

```
td.laclasses
{
    width: 140px;
    padding-right: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Is there a simple way for Wicket to encode the multiple string so that they show as multiple lines within a cell?

Comment: `(new Label("classnamelab", getClassNames(classesList).setEscapeModelStrings(false);` Also will work

Answer (score 3):

You should use `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.MultiLineLabel` for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiLineLabel` worked. I had to change the style as the data was inside a `<p>...</p>`.